# Datediff between a sliced date and a table date

Tags: powerbi-desktop

I am making a PowerBI report using a datetable and a table where I have startdates. I use the datetable in a slicer as a reference date. Now I want to calculate the number of days between the reference date and the startdates.

Can you help me?

Comment: You want to select one date from filter as reference and calculate in "table" for all rows its own days between? Or what?

Comment: My PowerBi is based on:

1. An Ax dynamics table with a validfrom date
2. A slicer with a reference date 
3. A measure for the slicer selected value like:
Slicer Selected Value = CALCULATE(MAX('Date'[Date]),ALLSELECTED('Date'))

What I need is a measure or column where the difference is calculated between the validfromdate and the slicer selected value. so yes, for all rows its own days between.

Comment: I have the solution. It's: Number of days between validfrom and slicer selected value DATEDIFF(CALCULATE(MAX(Leegstandsoverzicht[Validfrom])),Leegstandsoverzicht[Slicer Selected Value],DAY)